# HighCharts - Negative $ currency values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to format the y-axis and tooltip to add a dollar sign before values, using the labels formatter:

```
labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '$' + this.value;
            },
```

Which works a little too well. If I have a negative currency value, the '$' appears *before*  the negative sign.

How should the dollar sign be added so that it appears after the negative sign for negative values?

I apparently do not have enough points to post an image of what I'm talking about, so see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/elizabeth_shell/p6GDk/10/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check if its a neggative value and return according to that:

```
           formatter: function () {
                if(this.value  >= 0 ){
                    return '$' + this.value / 1000;
                }else{
                    return '-$' + this.value / 1000*-1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do I need to format my data differently for this method to work? This if/else returns a double negative sandwiched around the dollar sign: -$-1250.

Comment: You probably missed adding the `*-1` in the else, to convert it to possitive value

Comment: labels:{
                        format: '{value} €'
                    }